# JQuery Hover Menu only displays SOME information, but not all?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, hover

I provided a jsfiddle. The issue is, when I hover over 'Products' it only displays 'Cranes', 'Ergonomic Lifting' and 'Fall Protection', and only when I hover over THAT does it display the information underneath, until the nested ul's stop. When I hover over 'Products' I want EVERYTHING under Products, Cranes, etc. to be displayed at once. It's possible that it's my class and ID names, because they're all the same, so let me know if it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/miiicheellee/QTm2c/18/

The HTML is too long to put here, but it's in the jsfiddle.

CSS:

```
.red ul {

list-style-type: none;

/* takes bullets off of Products, Solutions Center, etc. */

}

.red li ul {

position: absolute;

/* rest of navigation doesn't move on dropdown */

}

.red ul.mega-menu {

position: relative;

width: 100%;

}

.red ul.mega-menu li {

float: left;

font-size: 16px;

font-weight: bold;

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

}

.sub-container {

display: none;

}
```

And JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("li.dc-mega-li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("div.sub-container").toggle();

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS only fix is adding something like:

```
.dc-mega-li:hover ul ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Will display all the lists on hover of the parent `li`.

/*** EDIT ***/

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QTm2c/21/)

}
I would remove the rule off `.sub-container` and hide/show the `ul` lists instead:

```
/* .sub-container {
    display: none;
} */

.dc-mega-li ul  {
    display:none;
}

.dc-mega-li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but this doesn't fix the issue of all of the child list items under 'Cranes' not displaying.

Comment: @user3802315 are you trying to show the first child of the first menu? OR all the lists that are under the parent `li`

Comment: all the lists under the parent li.

Comment: yay thank you! Your edit is what I was looking for. =)

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the jquery bit you had either. It's unnecessary

Comment: yeah I noticed that.. I originally had made a mega menu in css3 but it needs to be compatible with IE and it wasn't... so I switched to jquery. But this will probably work, so thank you.